# Expanding and retracting dropdown list in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, drop-down-menu, uipickerview

I'm starting off developing an iPhone app. I need to present a drop down box for the customer to pick a value which will essentially be sent downstream to a database upon submit. I'm clearly using a `UIPickerView` for the drop down list, built from IB.

Once my view loads, the Drop down list is enabled, with all values showing.

Question is:

1. Can I only expand the drop down list once it's clicked?
2. Can I retract the list once the user selects a value?

I'm thinking very web-centric in terms of drop-downs, but I could have this all wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your view controller needs to implement the **UIPickerViewDataSource** as well as the **UIPickerViewDelegate**. In the XIB of the UIPickerView you need to link the File's Owner with the UIPickerView's delegate and datasource.

Like in the UITabelDataSource you need to provide the number of components (table: sections) inside **[numberOfComponentsInPickerView]**. Then you need to provide the number of rows for each component in **[numberOfRowsInComponent]**. Finally you need to provide the title for the each entry inside **[titleForRow]**.

Now to bring everything to life you can use **[didSelectRow]** to load the next component if the previous one was selected.

**Attention:** UIPickerView has a little bug not to call **[didSelectRow]** when the component is filled / changed. In order to make it work more smoothly I added a "None" entry as the first entry which is a non-selection and does not cause the next component to be loaded.

This is a rudimentary code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 3; // Number of Components aka Columns
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if( component == 0 ) {
        return [self.firstColumnEntries count] + 1;
    } else if( component == 1 ) {
        return [self.secondColumnEntries count] + 1;
    } else if( component == 2 ) {
        return [self.thirdColumnEntries count] + 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSLog( @"titleForRow(), component: %d, row: %d", component, row );
    NSDictionary *item = nil;
    if( row == 0 ) {
        return @"  ---  ";
    } else {
        int correctedRow = row - 1;
        if( component == 0 ) {
            item = [self.firstColumnEntries objectAtIndex:correctedRow];
        } else if( component == 1 ) {
            item = [self.secondColumnEntries objectAtIndex:correctedRow];
        } else if( component == 2 ) {
            item = [self.thirdColumnEntries objectAtIndex:correctedRow];
        }
        return [item objectForKey:@"name"]; // My objects are NSDictionarys
    }
}

- (void) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    DLog( @"SSVC.didSelectRow(), component: %d, row: %d", component, row );
    ActionRequest *action = nil;
    if( row == 0 ) {
        if( component == 0 ) {
            [self refreshFirstColumn:self.firstColumnEntries];
        } else if( component == 1 ) {
            ...
        }
    } else {
        // Last Column is selected. Now selection is complete
        ...
    }
}
```

Because the UIPickerView takes away a lot of space and you cannot change it size I would recommend to place it on an additional UIView (make the rest transparent) and display it when the user selected the field that is assigned to the value (UITextField). When the selection is done (either when last value is selected or when the user enter a button) you let the View disappear and set the value onto the UITextField. Make sure that the UITextField cannot be edited and that entering it make the View with the Picker View appear. When done make sure that you also move to the next field.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options:

1. Probably easiest for a beginner: push a new view (either as a modal view or onto the nav stack) that presents the list either as a table view where they click the item they want or as a pickerView where it scrolls.
2. Review the twitter app 'my profile' view.  While I haven't done this personally, I think it's simply using the didSelectRowAtIndex to determine which section the user clicked and then filling an array of values for that section before calling [tableView reloadData]